# C# Bad Request - Error in Query Syntax

Tags: c#, silverlight, sql-server-2012

Good day all. in my silverlight c# program, i tried to save some string with slash (/) into sql server. eg: 123/ABC but got bad request error...i am not sure whether this error because of c# or wcf limitation. anyone knows the solution for this issue, pls kindly help me out

i have a textbox with the value: 123/ABC
then i called this save function to connect to service:

```
_svc.BeginSaveChanges(SaveChangesOptions.Batch, OnChangesSaved, _svc);
```

upon save, got this bad request error. i searched and found out that because of the slash (/)...

[enter image description here][1]

[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/y4zgs.png : Bad error img

Comment: Please take a few seconds to read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. We can't help if you don't provide pertinent information.

Comment: Did you debug the code and check which line of code is causing the issue?

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya yes i have debugged the code, the error coming after going into wcf service. looks like wcf does not allow special character. I tried using Replace("/","//") but no avail

Comment: You, can not debug the wcf service?

Answer (score 1):

You need to debug the WCF service. Run it and put a break point in the method your client is calling to see why the error is being caused.

Most likely there is code that is building a SQL query from a string that is resulting in broken SQL code. The method should be updated to send your string values as a parameter query.

Comment: i hv debugged, but its not going into service. haish...it just pop up the error

Comment: ok.for first time create, it was successful. the issue coming when we want to update the record...